# Add tooltip to post titles in reputation section of profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, title, tooltips

I noticed that [reputation section in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) doesn't have tooltips for post titles:

> [image]

This looks inconsistently with other sections, and I suggest to add tooltips here too. Furthermore, tooltip will be useful for long titles which end-up with `...` (ellipses) on the screen.